# iMac 2013 Catalina using Epson printer prints with green cast but copies okay

Tags: imac, printing

I'm asking here on behalf of my daughter, who has an iMac from 2013, running Catalina; her printer is an Epson XP-6000. When she prints a colour picture, the paler parts come out with a green/blue cast; **she's had the iMac/printer combination for a couple of years now and had no problems whatsoever before now**.

**But here's the thing**: the cartridges are all full, the nozzle check looks perfect, and when we "**Copy**" using the scanner to print directly **the same image looks perfect**. That says to me that the printer is working correctly, and that there is something wrong with the connection to the iMac (or something is wrong with the iMac) -- but I'm a Windows man so I don't understand the details.

We have tried deleting the printer (including the /Library/Printers/Epson folder), reinstalling the driver from Epson Support, then adding the printer again, and that made no difference.

She says she cannot think of any change she might have made to the printer since the last time it printed properly. She doesn't print every week but she thinks it was working okay a couple of months ago.

Does anyone have any ideas please? I've struggled searching online because the vast majority of the suggestions are to do with changing cartridges, and we are pretty sure that isn't the problem (because it prints directly from the integrated scanner just fine).

Comment: It's likely to be a profile issue… first check colour matching - https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvQOk.jpg

Comment: To clarify - when a color photograph is printed using the copier function of the device, the print has the correct colors reproduced?

Comment: @IconDaemon: Correct. We have a colour image that was printed professionally some time ago; when we try to print that image from the iMac we have the green/blue cast, but if we put the professionally-printed version (of the same image) onto the scanner and choose "Copy", the image comes out with perfect colours.

Comment: What app are you using to print?

Comment: We have tried printing from the standard Mac image viewer, and from within Chrome, with the same results.

Comment: @Tetsujin: Thanks, I'll take a look at that this afternoon when I see her again.

Comment: @Tetsujin: If we bring up the Print dialogue box, directly below the Orientation choice there is a drop-down but it shows options Media & Quality, Layout, Paper Handling, Cover Page, and Watermark -- nothing about colour at all. Should I be looking somewhere else because it's an Epson?

Comment: Colour has to be managed *somewhere*. It's been 15 years since I last owned an Epson, but I wouldn't expect the control to be anywhere else. You say you had an image printed a while ago… what's the origin of the image? Your own photo [if so, taken by what], or…?

Answer (score 2):

Well, we managed to 'fix' it. We tried printing from a MacBook with the same result, and from an iPhone ditto. Then we had the idea of changing the media from the default to 'Plain Paper' and that worked from the MacBook, but when my daughter tried it from her iMac it still failed.

Then I noticed that she was automatically whacking the Quality up to 'High'. When she tried leaving it on 'Normal' the printout was perfect.

I still don't quite see how either of those two things could cause the blue/green cast to parts of the image, but there you go.

Thanks to everyone for getting involved.